# Add attribute to a point it shares line segment with in QGIS

Tags: qgis, point, attribute-joins

I have two point layers, say

- Point layer A and
- Point Layer B.
- I also have a line layer.

I want to transfer the attributes of the point layer A to Point Layer B, only if it shares the line segment.

I have tried join by nearest in QGIS and it takes up the nearest point attribute. I am new to QGIS and do not understand how this can be achieved.

Comment: Do you mean a line or a line segment? ie are points on the same line but different segments, or on different lines? And which attribute(s) are you looking to transfer? A screenshot would improve the question, as would some more details about the attributes of your point layers.

Comment: Can there be multiple B points that should be joined to one point A? If so what should happen then?

Answer (score 2):

**SETTING**

[image]

In the field calculator for each layer Point_A and Point_B create a new field "LineID" with the fowlling expression:

```
overlay_nearest('Line', $id, max_distance:=0.0001)[0]
```

'Line' is the name of your Line layer. With max_distance you can fit your snapping tolerane.

[image]

Now we join on Point_B layer Point_A with the field LineID

[image]